# Trouble implementing Django ImageKit

Tags: python, django, django-imagekit

I am using `Django ImageKit` And I have absolutely no idea how to go about implementing a user uploaded image for a profile the user will have. I have it here list in my models. All attempts I have worked out have failed. Can any please guide me to steps on how to go about this? Thank you in advance!

**Models.py**

```
from imagekit.models import ProcessedImageField
from imagekit.processors import ResizeToFill

class Account(models.Model):

    user = models.OneToOneField(AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name="account", verbose_name=_("user"))
    real_name = models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=True)
    birthday = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=2,blank=True)
    image_thumbnail = ProcessedImageField(upload_to='img/user_images/main',
                                           processors=[ResizeToFill(100, 50)],
                                           format='JPEG',
                                           null=True, 
                                           blank=True,
                                           options={'quality': 60})
```

Comment: I am sure you have read this: https://github.com/matthewwithanm/django-imagekit/blob/develop/README.rst. Just make sure you are not missing any steps. It is quite comprehensive.

Comment: Can you be more specific about the problem you're having and what you've tried? Your model looks fine at first glance. Is it just that you're unsure how to tie a form to it?